# Write the contents of Arraylist to txt file in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have ArrayList with following contents

```
public void add() {

    obj.add(1);
    obj.add(123456789);
    obj.add(1.222);
    obj.add(2.333);  

    obj.add(2);
    obj.add(9876541);
    obj.add(4.555);
    obj.add(7.888);



}
```

I want the contents of the ArrayList to be written in the txt file as follows

```
1,123456789,1.222,2.333
2,9876541,4.555,7,888
```

I have following code to write the contents to the file

```
  public void createCSV() {

    try {
        FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(
                "/home/data.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++) {

            out.write(String.valueOf(obj.get(i)));
            out.write(",");

        }
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JavaOp_CSV x = new JavaOp_CSV();
    x.add();
    x.createCSV();

}
```

As of now the contents in the file is

```
1,123456789,1.222,2.333,
```

Can anybody provide me with a logic to get the o/p as mention above?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the question 'how to get rid of the last comma' or 'How to insert an enter after 4 fields' or even something else?

Comment: I think you should use a different structure. I suppose that your `1` and `2` are "rows" in the output.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the comma and to insert enter after 4 fields too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the string you will later write to file, and keep a count `i` on the elements.

if `i % 4 == 0` - add a line break

 else: add a `','`.

Note: You need to avoid adding the new line at the first element, and possibly the last as well if `total_num_elements % 4 != 0`

It can be easily done duing post processing using [`StringBuilder.deleteCharAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, it has a join method that meets your need.

```
StringUtils.join(obj.toArray(), ',');
```

Or you can only determine whether it's the first element or the last element.